# Maven compile successful, but install failed

Tags: java, compiler-errors, maven-3, java-7

I am using `maven 3.2.2` and `jdk-1.7.0_60`. I am executing `mvn compile` for a particular project, the compilation succeeds. But when I run `mvn clean install` on the same component, I get the following error-

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/projects/myProject/src/mainTest.java:[105,56] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getIdFromName(java.lang.String)
  location: class java.lang.Object
```

What could be the reason behind this? Doesn't `mvn compile` actually compile everything? As far as I know, the only difference between `mvn compile` and `mvn clean install` is that the latter command copies the required jar.

Comment: does mvn clean compile work for you?

Comment: then try mvn clean test to see if your test resources are getting compiled, as indicated by izstas.

Comment: you know your test cases are not compiling, why not resolve the compilation error then. just work upon the error in build logs.

Comment: You are right. But I don't understand what the compiler is expecting in this case. the method `getIdFromName()` does contain a `String` as input argument and the return type is also a `String`.

Comment: share your mainTest.java

Comment: The name of the class is an alias. I cannot share my java class. My hands are tied!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Maven Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), you will notice that `test-compile` phase goes after `compile`, but before `install`.

Since the file which fails to compile is `mainTest.java`, looks like this is your problem:

> Doesn't `mvn compile` actually compile **everything**?

No, it doesn't compile test sources.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same, this started when I added unit test cases, what worked for me is, first run

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

Then again run

```
mvn clean install
```